# Is there a way to extract the coefficient of linear discriminant into a data frame?

Tags: r, lda, linear-discriminant

Using the `iris` dataset as an example, I understand to perform LDA, you can use this:

```
library(MASS) 
iris[1:4] <- scale(iris[1:4])
sample <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(iris), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7,0.3))
train <- iris[sample, ]
test <- iris[!sample, ] 

model <- lda(Species~., data=train)

#view model output
model
```

and it will return the group means, coefficient of linear discrimants and proportion of trace.

However, is there a way to extract the coefficient of linear discriminant into a dataframe?

Comment: Try `model$scaling`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can checkout the whole data strucutre with `str(model)` and with `model$scaling` you can get the data.frame with the linear discriminants